# perfect-scrollbar area doesn't scroll on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I've used [meteorjs](https://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/) to build my website, [blainehansenpiano.com](http://blainehansenpiano.com/), and it works and looks good on browsers and ipad. I'm using the [perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar) on the scrollable areas, and it is working fine.

I'm also using bootstrap3, so my site can be easily viewed on mobile. I have this template:

```
<template name="home">
    <div class="row body-film">
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            {{> backgroundPictures}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 block-film scroller">
            <div id="newsfeed">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Along with this `less`:

```
html, body, .container-fluid {
    .fill-height();
}
.body-film {
    .fill-height();
    background-color: @color;
}
.block-film {
    .fill-height();
    background-color: @different-color; 
}

.fill-height {
    height: 100%;
}

.scroller {
    .fill-height();
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
    html, body, .container-fluid, .body-film, .block-film, .scroller {
        height: auto !important;
        overflow-y: visible !important;
    }
}
```

The intended behavior is that while the site is sized from `.col-sm` to `.col-lg`, the blocks are sized to the window and the scrollbar handles all the movement. Then when the site is sized at `.col-xs` the columns are broken into blocks, the `height` and `overflow` are changed back, and that turns off the scrollbar and lets the native behavior take over.

On my browser this works great. When I resize my window to that small level, no scrollbars are displayed and things scroll naturally.

**However**, when I try this on mobile browsers (all of them that I've tried), the `.block-film` area that had the scroller attached to it simply doesn't respond to touch scrolls. If you scroll down into that area, you just get stuck.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Looking at the github README, `wheelPropogation` has a note: "Currently not supported for touch events". Do you need it for mobile? Why not do some user agent detecttion to stop from invoking it if so.

Comment: Well, that shouldn't matter. I'm not setting `wheelPropogation` to anything, and I don't want the event to propagate, I want the scroller *turned off entirely*, and for the native scroll behavior to take over. The scroller isn't appearing, which is what I want, but it's somehow still sabotaging the native scroll.

Comment: Would the second half of my comment prove a valid solution? To not call it altogether if the user agent is mobile?

Comment: That could work. How can I detect that?

Comment: Ill post in answer for formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working perfectly. The `window.innerWidth` lines up exactly with the Bootstrap column breakpoint.

```
var is_xs = window.innerWidth < 768;
if (!is_xs) {
    // initialize scroller
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the comments, since not calling perfect scroller on mobile is a valid solution, try doing some user agent detection as such:

```
var is_mobile = ((/Mobile|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Windows Phone/i).test(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera) ? true : false);

if ( !is_mobile ) {
  // whatever the init call is
  perfectScroller.init()
}
```

Comment: Although this is a good solution, I've realized it would be more robust  if I measured the `window.innerWidth` and compared it the the bootstrap `.col-xs` breakpoint of 768 px. That `innerWidth` aligns perfectly.